# How to call `unregisterFormatType` for a specific block type in Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm using Gutenberg for a Wordpress site and would like to hide the "Bold" button in the Richtext editor only for the `core/pullquote` block type, but still allow it for all others.

For format types that I don't want anywhere, using `unregisterFormatType` has worked just fine:

`wp.richText.unregisterFormatType( 'core/text-color' )`

Is there a way to invoke this function just for the one block type? I've seen suggestions that customize `allowedFormats` in the `<Richtext>` element returned by the block type's `Edit` function, but I'd really rather not extend the source of the core block if there's an easier way.

I've considered a CSS solution for the editor as well, but hoping there's a less hacky way.

Comment: You can get Block Type using 'getBlockType' if you know the block name. Eg. getBlockType( 'core/paragraph' ) and then use IF condition to unregisterFormatType. You may explore more at Block Editor Handbook at WordPress Developer Resources. https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-blocks/

Comment: That I can do. I'm just not sure how to invoke `unregisterFormatType` on a specific block instance since it seems to edit the entire Richtext editor for everyone.